# Cache (potentially) changing values from the database in java

Tags: java, sql-server, caching, ehcache

What is the current recommended approach for storing cached data in Java

I am looking for a particular approach that will update the cache when an insert or an update happens to particular table(s).

Ideally this should happen as quickly as possible so as to avoid any issues when cross referencing data.

Is there a technology that provides this (such as ehcache) or an advised programming standard which i could follow.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use spring framework by any chance ?

Comment: I am not using Spring unfortunately

Comment: Is your use case purging the cache when *you* update the table, or when *anyone* updates it in the DB, even outside your application?

Comment: When anyone updates the table - i would like my cache to be updated - whether that be a new insert / update or delete

Answer (score 2):

[Spring cache abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) ? There are a lot of implemented cache providers like Ehcache or Redis.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to springframework in your application you can do something like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="yournamescache")
public List<String> getNames(){
     return yourDao.findAll();
}

@CacheEvict(value="yournamescache") //a value has changed so clear cache when this method executes
public void updateNames(x) {
    yourDao.update(x);

}
```

Behind the scenes use Ehcache for example.

you can find more information here [Spring cache abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Comment: does this work with multiple instances of the same application

Answer (score 1):

I will talk about Ehcache but there should be similar features in other caching framework.

It really depends on how transactional you need to be. Two features in Ehcache might help you.

- XA to have Ehcache committing to the cache in the same transaction as your DB
- [Loader-writer](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/writers.html). This will load the data from the database when the case is queried and write to the cache when writing to the database. So they both stay in sync

Of course, both can be used under Spring-Cache if needed.